# Java throw The Network Adapter could not establish the connection on Oracle after few hundred of transaction

Tags: java, sql, oracle

i have a strange problem here.

i have a java apps that connect to oracle 10g db at different host, running insert records few thousand with no error.

then when i move the java apps to run in the host of oracle 10g db (the host also running few apps that connect to the oracle db), after 300++ insert, java will start throwing "`The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`"

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at pckDataAccess.clsDBAccess.BuildDBConnection(clsDBAccess.java:231)
```

this is strange because the it only happen when i connect locally, and it happened after 300+ success insert. I tried to put a sleep for 2 second every 100 insert, the insert can up to 600~700 transaction, then the network error come out again.

Also, i have my statement, and connection closed in finally block.

Does anyone know why this  happened?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check whether you are having a leaking Connection, or over-using your resources for example after using a connection check that the connection is disposed. This Helps to free up resources.

Comment: Also if possible use batch insert using JDBC..   statement.addBatch(query);
 
statement.executeBatch();

Comment: hi stanley, what you mean disposed? is connection.close() and statement.close() consider disposed?